# How to prevent ScrollView from automatically scrolling to a focused TextInput when the keyboard pops up?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, textinput

When user taps on a `TextInput` inside a `ScrollView`, the latter automatically scrolls down so the text field doesn't get covered by the keyboard.

Although this is a very useful and indeed expectable behavior, is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

I want the `ScrollView` to stay at the exact same scroll position after the keyboard pops up, even if the text field gets covered by it as a result.

Here's an example:

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {ScrollView, Text, TextInput} from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>

                {/* Something to fill the screen */}
                <Text style={{fontSize: 70}}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</Text>

                {/* TextInput on the keyboard level */}
                <TextInput style={{borderWidth: 1}} />

            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: so, what you are trying to say is, if the keyboard is enabled you want to disable scroll? so that it exactly stays at the same position?

Comment: @tajammul1996 when user taps on the text field, the keyboards pop up and the `ScrollView` gets automatically scrolled down to make the text field visible on the screen. I want to disable that automatic scrolling, so that after tapping the text field the scroll position stays the same.

Comment: then try using scrollEnabled={false} when using keyboard. use keyboard handler and change state, based on that enable or disable scrollEnabled attribute of scrollview.

Comment: @tajammul1996 I already tried that. scrollEnabled={false} only prevents the user from scrolling using gestures and does not affect automatic scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

set screen height for scrollview it will remove auto scroll

example

```
//get window height
const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");



//scrollview
<ScrollView style={{height:height}}>
  //your text input
</ScrollView>
```